# Two flows call Ajax method, one needs extra processing at the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

Newbie question about Ajax and promises.

I have two JS functions, `flowA()` and `flowB()`, which both call an Ajax fetch function, defined as follows:

```
function ajaxGetQuestions() {
   $.ajax( {
      // DB call..
   }).done({
      // Build a DOM structure with results...
   });
}
```

- `flowA()` calls this method without anything extra.
- `flowB()` needs to call this method and also modify one of the elements created by the success callback.

How should I structure my code and jQuery promises?

Obviously I don't want to do

```
function flowA() {
   ajaxGetQuestions();
}
function flowB() {
   ajaxQuestions();
   extraSteps();
}
```

With promises, I don't want to chain any .done callbacks. The Ajax function is **shared (reusable) and only does one thing**. It's up to the outside Flow B to do its extra thing after the reusable Ajax code is done.

Comment: What if you passed in a flag that you could use to do the extra modification inside the ajax get questions?

Comment: thanks I thought of that but was wondering if there was a better way. Based on Thomas' answer I can use then() for a Promise return object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function ajaxGetQuestions() {
   return $.ajax( { // this returns a promise
      // DB call..
   }).done({
      // Build a DOM structure with results...
   });
}
```

And then

```
function flowA() {
   ajaxGetQuestions();
}
function flowB() {
   ajaxQuestions()
     .then(extraSteps);
}
```

Promises are great for that kind of task!
;o)

Comment: It worked. Thanks. For some reason Firebug never stops inside the Then(..) Promise code so I can't debug it but I see that it works.

Comment: I have little experience with firebug, but chrome developer tools can debug `.then` promises